# interlinking two listbox with commandbutton

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed an userform, with two Listbox multiple option.

I have populated the listbox1 with "locations" eg:Germany, USA, UK ;  from sheet list.

I have populated listbox2, with the "locations"eg:Germany, USA, UK  from sheet list_Man.

My objective is to filter the rows in my sheet "result", depending upon the locations selection. The location are available in column L and M of my sheet "result"

I have an function Do filter for this.

```
Sub DoFilter()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim strCriteria() As String
Dim arrIdx As Integer
Dim xRow As Integer
arrIdx = 0
For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List.Cells)
If List.Cells(xRow, 2) = True Then
ReDim Preserve strCriteria(0 To arrIdx)
strCriteria(arrIdx) = List.Cells(xRow, 3)
arrIdx = arrIdx + 1
End If
Next xRow
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
If arrIdx = 0 Then
Ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
Else
Ws.Range("A:R").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Array(strCriteria), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If
End Sub
```

[![this is the user form that have been designed. The Listbox1 has the locations from the list sheet and the listbox2 has the locations from the List_Man sheet. 
The filter option, according to the selection in the listbox, filters the column L and M of the sheet "Result". exit buton, unloads and returns to the original sheet clearing the filter option.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf5q3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf5q3.png)

Now the userform works in such a way that, if I select both the listbox, then I get the option filtered.

I would like to have an code in my command button, in such a way that

[image: If I select "USA" in listbox1, then I would like to see only the filtered rows in my sheet "Result" for the listbox1]
[![If I am selecting more than one option in listbox1,"USA and UK" and in listbox2, I am selecting "Germany", then I need the filtered rows in result sheet for these option".

also the case in viceversa should be possible. If I select only location2 in listbox2, I should be able to see the filtered rows in the sheet"result".
if I am selecting more than one option in listbox2, and one option in listbox1, then I should be able to see the result accordingly.

I would like to have a code in my command button "Filter" for such condition.

Any lead would be helpful.

this is the code, I am using in my listbox
    Private Sub ListBox2_Change()
    Dim listboxCounter As Integer
    For listboxCounter = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(listboxCounter) = True Then
       List_Man.Cells(listboxCounter + 2, 2) = True
    Else
      List_Man.Cells(listboxCounter + 2, 2) = False
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
this is the code for my userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_activate()
Dim xRow As Integer
Dim yows As Integer

For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List.Range("A:A"))
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem List.Cells(xRow, 3).Value
        If List.Cells(xRow, 2) = True Then
            .Selected(xRow - 2) = True
        Else
            .Selected(xRow - 2) = False
        End If
    End With
Next xRow
ListBox1.Height = (xRow - 1) * 15

For yrow = 2 To Last(1, List_Man.Range("A:A"))
With ListBox2
.AddItem List_Man.Cells(yrow, 3).Value
If List_Man.Cells(yrow, 2) = True Then
.Selected(yrow - 2) = True
Else
.Selected(yrow - 2) = False
End If
End With
Next yrow
ListBox2.Height = (xRow - 1) * 15
End Sub
```

Comment: There will be data loss in this case.
For example, if you select USA in list1 and Germany in list 2, Filter will only select the data having only Germany in list2 and USA in list 1.

Comment: @nishitdey sorry, it is not clear

Comment: Use this code for the filteration

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$27").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=(reference to the listbox)

Comment: @nishitdey Could you help me in the code :( I am lost :( is it possible, to edit in my code :(

Comment: @nishitdey All I would like to have now is, If I select one or many option in listbox1, leaving the listbox2 unselected, I should be able to see the filtered result, (my dofilter code). the current code, works, when both the listbox are selected.

Comment: Please mail me the code and the sheet. Thanks